# SVN copy equivalent if using Git-SVN bridge

Tags: git, svn, version-control, copy, git-svn

Im using the Git-SVN bridge for a remote Subversion repository. Now, I need something like the `svn copy` command in Git / Git-SVN, so that it looks like I used `svn copy` to the remote SVN repository.

As far as I know, `svn copy file` keeps the history for the `file` for the copied `file` and also it is a "diff" to the old `file` if new copied `file` is changed.

Is there something that I can use to realize that behavior using the Git-SVN bridge?

Comment: why would you need `svn copy` except for creating branches/tags which is covered by git-svn? Even if you do, you can always workaround by executing `svn cp` directly, bypassing the git-svn bridge and importing the change back via `git svn fetch`.

Comment: You need it, if you want to copy a file for which you need the history and the new file should be stored as diff to the original file. I already figured out, that I can do it with `svn cp` SVN server-side and the get it with `git svn rebase`.